# How Rowbottom can $\aleph_{\omega}$ be?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

A current unknown hypothesis is whether or not $\aleph_\omega$ can be Rowbottom. It is well known that the consistency strength of such a conjecture is stronger than that of the existence of a measurable cardinal, however there is no known upper bound of consistency strength (as far as I am aware of).

A possible way to find the consistency strength of this is by approximating it in little steps, generalizing Rowbottom-ness to a weaker form. This led me to this question.

---

**Let $RW=\min\{n\in\omega:\aleph_\omega\not\rightarrow[\omega_\omega]_{\aleph_n,<\aleph_1}^{<\omega}\}$.**

By definition, $\aleph_\omega$ is Rowbottom if and only if $RW$ does not exist, so if it is inconsistent for there to be a measurable cardinal, then $RW$ exists, and if $0^{\#}$ does not exist, then $RW$ exists.

Clearly, $RW>0$. If $RW=0$, then it would mean that there is a partition $f:[\omega_\omega]^{<\omega}\rightarrow\omega$ such that $f"H$ is uncountable for some $H$, meaning $\omega$ is uncountable.

Futhermore, Kanamori in his "The Higher Infinite" provides a theorem sufficient to prove that $RW=\min\{n\in\omega\setminus\{0\}:(\aleph_\omega,\aleph_n)\not\twoheadrightarrow(\aleph_\omega,\aleph_0)\}$. By the definition of the square bracket partition property, $RW=\min\{n\in\omega:\exists f:[\omega_\omega]^{<\omega}\rightarrow\omega_n\forall H\in[\omega_\omega]^{\aleph_\omega}(|f"H|>\aleph_0)\}$.

Kanamori also provides in the same text that if $\aleph_\omega\rightarrow[\omega_\omega]^{<\omega}_{\aleph_n,<\aleph_1}$, then $\aleph_1$ is inaccessible in $L$. Therefore $V=L\rightarrow RW=1$ and $RW^L=1$, and therefore as well, $Con(\text{ZFC}+RW>1)\rightarrow Con(\text{ZFC}+\text{inaccessible})$.

---

Quick recap:

- $\aleph_\omega$ is Rowbottom if and only if $RW$ does not exist
- $\neg\text{Con}(\text{ZFC}+\text{measurable})\rightarrow RW$ exists
- $\neg(0^{\#}$ exists$)\rightarrow RW$ exists
- $RW>0$
- $RW=\min\{n\in\omega\setminus\{0\}:(\aleph_\omega,\aleph_n)\not\twoheadrightarrow(\aleph_\omega,\aleph_0)\}$
- $RW=\min\{n\in\omega:\exists f:[\omega_\omega]^{<\omega}\rightarrow\omega_n\forall H\in[\omega_\omega]^{\aleph_\omega}(|f"H|>\aleph_0)\}$
- $RW>1\rightarrow\aleph_1$ is inaccessible in $L$
- $V=L\rightarrow RW=1$, $L\models (RW=1)$

---

**Questions: If $RW>1$, then does $0^{\#}$ exist? Is there some $n$ such that if $RW>n$, then $\aleph_\omega$ is Rowbottom? What are some upper bounds on consistency strength for some of these?**

Comment: I don't see your last comment. Compactness way produce non-standard natural numbers.

Comment: Well, I really meant for $n$ to be a formula, which just meant $0+1+1+1...$ ($n$ $1$s), where $+1$ is just the successor function and $0$ is the empty set.

Comment: @Keith That is irrelevant to the issue raised by Mohammad.

Comment: Well, if for every $n$, $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC}+RW>n)$, then for any finite set $N$ of natural numbers $n$, $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC}+RW>n)$ (because it is consistent that $RW>\max(N)$).

Comment: Your compactness comment is indeed incorrect. All compactness would tell you is that there is a model of ZFC which satisfies $RW>k$ for every true natural number $k$. However, this model may itself have nonstandard natural numbers, so it *won't* satisfy "$RW>n$ for every natural number $n$."

Comment: So?${{{}}}{}{}$

Comment: Correct, I am removing that bullet point. Good eye.

Comment: If you drop choice and assume the axiom of determinacy, then $\aleph_\omega$ is Rowbottom. (See Kleinberg's book.) Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: @William That is a really fascinating detail, but it sadly doesn't pertain to the question as I was assuming choice.